# How to create a function which will allow user to enter price with range?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a function which will allow user to enter only price and price with range.
Here is my output:

```
1,223,456.52-12,364.69
```

Here use should be able to add only one (-) dash and it should be only between two price.

Price should be formatted in currency format when user entering digits. Other then user can not add (-) dash or (.) dot unless user enter any digits or number.

I do not want to use any plugin for this.

How can i do that?
Thanks

Comment: you could validate the input using Regexp

Comment: @JaromandaX can you post Regexp for that it here? I'm new being for regexp.

Comment: did you want the range to be hi-low or low-hi or either?

Comment: @Meteor It sounds like there could be a much better way to solve this, with your desired spec being bad ux. Preventing users from pressing certain keys is almost always bad.

Comment: @JaromandaX no in range it should be normal , user can input any value.

Comment: This is not pricing specifically, but has some good examples of better ways of solving your problem. http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38042/complicated-date-field-with-range-option

Comment: you may try this [regex] https://regex101.com/r/yY1xM5/1

Comment: `no in range it should be normal` - what does that even mean? do you want the users to be able to input a range using low to high values, or high to low values, or either way?

Comment: @JaromandaX either way.

Comment: *"currency format"* for which currency? Most people would consider commas optional. Some countries use commas for the decimal separator.

Comment: @nnnnnn for India and Russian.